# How to save and restore current tex state (registers)?

Tags: luatex, tex-core

I'm trying to get tex output (some changes will be done) so I put everything in a box and traverse the nodes. Everything would be fine except global definitions. First attempt was to use `\globaldef` to avoid them in this box, but there a problems with font assignments and some other commands.

Now I'm thinking of to save tex registers (\count, \toks, ..) and restore them after the box is done. But problem is that I cant find info is this register global or not. Of course there still be evaluated global defs but maybe they are not so harmful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local tex_registers = {}
function savetexstate(totalcount, totaltoks, totaldimen)
    tex_registers = {[totalcount] = "count", [totaldimen] = "dimen",  [totaltoks] ="toks"}
    for total, value in pairs (tex_registers) do
        for i=0, total do
            -- it's not safe to take 10000 blindly but for now don't mind
            local idx = 10000 + i 
            if tex[value][i] then
                -- Globaly saving tex registers \count10001=\count1, \count10002=\coun2, ...
                if value == "toks" then
                    tex.sprint([[\global\]] .. value .. idx ..  "={" .. tex[value][i] .. [[}]])
                else
                    tex.sprint([[\global\]] .. value .. idx ..  [[=\the\]] .. value .. i)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function restoretexstate()
    for total, value in pairs (tex_registers) do
        for i=0, total do
            local idx = 10000 + i
            if tex[value][idx] then
                if value == "toks" then
                    -- Globaly restoring tex registers \count1=\count10001, \count2=\coun10002, ...
                    tex.sprint([[\global\]] .. value .. i ..  "={" .. tex[value][idx] .. [[}]])
                else
                    tex.sprint([[\global\]] .. value .. i ..  [[=\the\]] .. value .. idx)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
\end{luacode*}


\makeatletter

\def\dosomething#1{%
  #1% HERE NORMAL LATEX OUTPUT
  \bgroup
    %% is there a better way to get total number of allocated registers?
    \globaldefs=-\@ne    % no global defs
    \newcount\tmpcount
    \edef\totalcountnum{\the\allocationnumber}%
    \newtoks\tmptoks
    \edef\totaltoksnum{\the\allocationnumber}%
    \newdimen\tmpdimen
    \edef\totaldimennum{\the\allocationnumber}%
    \globaldefs=\z@      % normal global defs
    \directlua{savetexstate(\totalcountnum, \totaltoksnum, \totaldimennum)}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\vbox{#1}}%
    % <<< here lua code traveses box 0 >>>
    \directlua{restoretexstate()}%
  \egroup
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newtoks\fee 
\newtoks\foo 
\fee={\textbf{A}}
\foo={\textbf{1}}

{
  {
    \dosomething{
      TEXT 
      \global\fee=\expandafter{\the\fee B} 
      \foo=\expandafter{\the\foo 2} 
      \stepcounter{equation} 
      }
    \fee={C}
    \foo={3}
  }
}
\showthe\fee  % output \textbf{A}B (OK)
\showthe\foo  % output \textbf{1}2 (WRONG) should be \textbf{1} 
\makeatletter
\showthe\c@equation  % output 1 (OK)
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Problem is in `restoretexstate()` where I assign backed up registers globaly:
`tex.sprint([[\global` (don't understand how to use tex.set so I use tex.sprint) 
If I could test some how that it was global register I could only then restore it globaly.

Is it even possible to save tex current state at all? Maybe I'm doing nonsense?
Is it other ways to scan tex output without adding it to the box? I can't output that box because I change some things in it. 
Using LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013041409

Comment: Registers are not “global or local”. They can be set globally or locally and TeX doesn't mind if you perform both kinds of actions on a register, except maybe running out of save stack memory.

Comment: If something is being set globally, there's a reason: 'resetting' after the box won't really be a good idea. Also, what are you doing about macros? For example, if someone sets a `\label` it creates a global macro ...

Comment: Side remark: your luatex version is rather old. Current is 1.07.

Comment: `\label` is not a problem because it is already outputted (`\def\dosomething#1{#1....`). Problems can be if one uses \global appending to the macro then I will not know that. But is there any possibility to know that this register or command is set globally?

Comment: essentially no not unless you redefine all assignment commands to record that information, but you haven't really given much information on what is your real use case, what are you trying to restore?

Comment: there is no need for your hacks with globaldefs to find the allocated registers simply look in \count10 (for counts) or \count11 for dimens etc, but note that code can (as yours does) use unallocated registers and use `\count10010` also `\extrafloats` takes count registers "from the top" not from the allocationnumber.

Comment: To check `\count10` was my first  attempt but then I found that `etex.sty` uses \count260 (if I remember correct). That's why I thought it will be more universal. Lutatex could have `tex.getregistertotal("toks")` function to get number of allocated register.

Comment: David, I'm trying to write in a txt file all the text what will be outputted in PDF from that parameter (lets say from `\section`, `\author`) so I change encoding to similar to PU to get rid of accents.

Comment: no one should be using etex.sty with luatex in any reasonably current setup (I note you are using a very old version) "Lutatex could have tex.getregistertotal("toks") function to get number of allocated register" no the luatex engine knows nothing about allocation it is purely a feature of the macros being used.

Comment: why do you need to reset any tex definitions in order to get that text? you can just iterate through the nodes and extract (or change) and nodes corresponding to glyphs

Comment: note that the interfaces in luatex for beta 0.76 are _vastly_ different to the interfaces for anything from 1.0 onwards (current version is 1.07) so if writing any code in this area I would start by updating your tex system as your code is unlikely to work after an update otherwise.

Comment: You are right. It is better directly inspect nodes without any additional boxes. But it's later it's hard to get unicode glyphs from output. For example I've locally changed `\def\frac##1##2{##1/##2}` or `\textcircled{1}` chenged to  1 + ⃝ (20DD). So after  output it's harder to understand what you need to do

Comment: Is it correct that it's not possible to get outputed nodes while paragraph is not finished without adding it to the box ? E.g: `foo \sometext{a \hbox{c} $\Gamma$ b}` to store text which will be outputed  to macro `\def\outputedtext{a c  b}`. `pre_output_filter` runs to late and `hpack_filter` does not see all the nodes?

Comment: @Linuxss you need to address your comment to David, otherwise he won't notice probably. Just start a new comment with `@David` and the system will offer autocompletion.

Comment: @David, is it correct that it's not possible to get outputed nodes while paragraph is not finished without adding it to the box ? E.g: `foo \sometext{a \hbox{c} $\Gamma$ b}\show\outputedtext` Where `\sometext` outputs parameter and stores outputed nodes to macro \def\outputedtext{a c  b} and with `\show\outputedtext` I could already see them? `pre_output_filter` runs to late and `hpack_filter does` not see all the nodes?

Comment: you don't need a callback, you can access the current list directly `abc\directlua{
n=node.last_node()
}xyz`  removes `c` as the node `n` but having got c you could put it back or use the node library to traverse the current horizontal list back to the indentation box.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle very interesting idea. And now I'll really need a newer luatex. Thanks, I'll try this method.

Comment: I don't think this question is really answerable as asked I suggest it's closed but feel free to ask a new one if you get stuck.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree.